# how does mongo db group by using aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

how attribute does mongodb uses to group by ?
do they use only the "_id" or the ( "_id" AND "Total departments")
I am slightly confused because "_id" and "Total Departments" are in the same curly bracket $group

```js
db.department.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "totalNumOfStaff": "$totalNumOfStaff",
        "budget": "$budget"
      },
      "Total departments": {
        $sum: "$budget"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your provided code sample, you are grouping by a composite key `{totalNumOfStaff, budget}`, which comes from 2 sources: `totalNumOfStaff` and  `budget` respectively. They are combined as the group key `_id`.

For `Total departments`, it is actually the aggregation depending on the group key `_id` or `{totalNumOfStaff, budget}`. You are doing `$sum` by every unique combination of the group key `{totalNumOfStaff, budget}`.

Comment: so mongoDB always uses the value in "_id" which is {totalNumOfStaff, budget} in this case to group by right?

Comment: @WorldTreeBoy `_id` is always being used as the key for `$group` stage. The definition of `_id` is specified by you.

Comment: yup i did. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can compare [objects also](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects)

Each document that is about to be grouped will get a grouping key, that
its that document `{"totalNumOfStaff": "$totalNumOfStaff","budget": "$budget"}`

Based on the comparison algorithm (comparing the field names and values in order, see the link), it will decide to which group it belongs or create a new group for it.

In the above example same group is if same `totalNumOfStaff` AND same `budget`(order matters) and for each group sums the budget.